# Call controller method from different class

Tags: apex, controller, class, standardcontroller

How can I call a method structured like this:

```
public with sharing class Calculator {
    private ApexPages.StandardController l;
    public Calculator(ApexPages.StandardController l) {
    ...
}
```

From another Apex class (**for a batch calculation**):

```
public void calculateLeads() {
    List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id, Lead_Generation_Date__c FROM Lead ORDER BY Lead_Generation_Date__c];
    for(Lead l: leads) {
        Calculator(l.Id); // what do I pass here?!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just create an instance of a `StandardController` and pass that.

```
public void calculateLeads() {
    List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id, Lead_Generation_Date__c FROM Lead ORDER BY Lead_Generation_Date__c];
    for(Lead l: leads) {
        Calculator controller = new Calculator(new ApexPages.StandardController(l));
    }
}
```

That said, if you're calling a controller from a batch to do (presumably) some calculation, then really for a code architecture point of view you should create a third class that provides a method to do the calculation (ideally taking a list of `Lead` objects) and reference that from both the batch and the controller that you've already created.

Comment: Thanks so much. Agreed, too, this is a one-off is all so shortcuts aren't all that bad.

Comment: Although your solution does give me a `Method does not exist or incorrect signature` error.

Comment: My bad, you need to create a new instance of the controller. Will update.